# Limit of the ratio of the arc and the respective chord

Tags: geometry, limits

I've always seen that if a circle's arc taken small enough can be treated (and is treated) as  a straight line.
But can anyone give a proof for it?
That is, prove as the angle between two radii of the same circle approaches zero, the ratio of the arc subtended by the angle and the respective chord approached 1. I request simplicity.

Comment: Can someone please tell me the mathjax syntax for writing lim?

Comment: `$\lim_{x\to a}$` gives $\lim_{x\to a}$ and `$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}$` gives $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}$.

Comment: It's basic geometry/trigonometry to find formulas for the length of the arc and the length of the chord, then set up the ratio and find the limit. You've done some Calculus? Seen things like $\lim_{x\to0}(\sin x/x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider a circular arc with radius 1 subtending angle $2\theta$. The length of this arc is $2 \theta$.  The length of the chord is $2 \sin \theta$.

(Consider the case where you have a circular arc from $-\theta$ to $\theta$, with zero at positive $x$ axis.  Then, the chord endpoints are at $(\cos\theta, \pm\sin\theta)$, and therefore the chord length is $2 \sin\theta$.

The ratio of the chord length to the arc length is
$$\frac{2 \sin\theta}{2 \theta} = \frac{\sin\theta}{\theta} \tag{1}\label{1}$$

If you know calculus, particularly [limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)), then it suffices to note that
$$\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin\theta}{\theta} = 1 \tag{2}\label{2}$$

In this particular case that boils down to [l'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule): when we have $\lim_{x \to r} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ with $f(r)=0$ and $g(r)=0$, and both $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, then $$\lim_{x \to r} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to r} \frac{ \frac{d f(x)}{d x} }{ \frac{d g(x)}{d x}}$$
(or in simple terms, when the limit is of form $0/0$, the ratio of the *slopes* of the two functions gives us the limit). L'Hôpital's rule is more versatile than that, but that's the part that applies here.

In this case,
$$\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta} = \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\cos \theta}{1} = \left . \cos \theta \right \rvert_{\theta = 0} = 1 \tag{3}\label{3}$$

Another way to consider this is to expand $\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}$ as a [power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Power_series_expansion):
$$\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta} = \frac{\theta}{\theta} - \frac{\theta^3}{\theta 3!} + \frac{\theta^5}{\theta 5!} - \frac{\theta^7}{\theta 7!} + ... = 1 - \frac{\theta^2}{3!} + \frac{\theta^4}{5!} - \frac{\theta^6}{7!} + ...$$
When $\theta \to 0$, all components except the constant go to zero, so at zero this function has value $1$.

A yet another way is the [Sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) view.
$$\operatorname{sinc} x = \begin{cases}
\frac{\sin x}{\pi x}, & \text {Normalized, used in digital signal processing and information theory} \\
\frac{\sin x}{x}, & \text {Unnormalized, used in mathematics and in general} \\
\end{cases} \tag{4}\label{4}$$
It is a well-known function, and for both normalized and unnormalized variants, $\operatorname{sinc}(0) = 1$. Thus, we can say that for a circular arc subtending an angle $2 \theta$, the ratio between the chord length and the arc length is $$\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta} = \operatorname{sinc}(\theta)$$using the unnormalized (no $\pi$ factor) convention.  Since $\operatorname{sinc}(0) = 1$, the ratio tends towards $1$ the smaller the angle $2\theta$ is.

Comment: Very well explained:). Thanks

Comment: It was so obvious. I can't believe I posted this question before thinking myself. Well, I guess it worked out.

Comment: Using l'Hopital requires knowledge of the derivative of the sine function. Working out the derivative of the sine function from the Newton quotient requires knowing $\lim_{x\to0}((\sin x)/x)=0$. So using l'Hopital here is circular reasoning (no pun intended).

Comment: @GerryMyerson: (You've a typo, $\lim_{x\to 0}((\sin x)/x) = 1$, or possibly you meant $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin x = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} x = 0$?) Yes, I tried to express $\eqref{3}$ as the expansion/reasoning behind of $\eqref{2}$, and not a separate rule.  No, you can also work out the derivative of the sine function from the power series expansion.  But yes, it could well be argued that what I wrote is circular reasoning, as I'm not a mathematician, and see, to consider some of the properties of trigonometric functions as axiomatic (contrary to what mathematicians do).  Sorry!

Comment: @GerryMyerson: If you have a more (mathematically) robust but equally simple proof for us non-mathematicians, please do post that as an answer.  (I'd be happy for VizDracViz to change the accepted answer to that one instead.)  I am not good at math proofs, so that's why I described more than one approach towards one; I did not intend for these to be taken as a proof, just point towards one.

Comment: Yes, a typo, very careless of me. Finding the derivative of the sine function from its power series is also circular, since you get the power series from knowing the derivative. You can find a purely geometric proof at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_of_trigonometric_functions#Limit_of_sin(%CE%B8)/%CE%B8_as_%CE%B8_tends_to_0 and also in any good intro Calculus text.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks, that's a good point!  It's been almost three decades since I took Intro to Calculus myself.  Since then, I've mostly dabbled with various physics stuff and 3D graphics.  Hopefully explains my deficiencies in math..